# Single channel Image annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, computer-vision, data-annotations, semantic-segmentation

I'm working on Mask(Labels) generation for Semantic segmentation problem

I have a NumPy array of `250x321`. It's a single-channel image. I've to annotate this image. But since this is a single-channel image, when trying to save it in the normal mode of `matplotlib.pyplot`, dimensions are changed along with a change in the channel (4). When storing just a single-channel image in `png` format, the image is all black, hence unable to annotate the image.

So I'm unable to annotate `png` format image (All Black) and also unable to use normal `matplotlib.pyplot` save function (Dim are changed along with channels)

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this job!

I've used code given below

```
plt.imshow(data[:, 400:650].T)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('/content/new.png',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

The above code is generating an array of shape `245x315x4` when used `plt.imread` when in the original array was of shape `250x321x1`.

Comment: It could be a few things for example a data type (are your images frloat or int) issue. However, it's difficult to help you without any code. In this particular case, you should create a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Ash, I've edited the question and added code, pls see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to just save the image, avoid using `plt.savefig` and instead use either `plt.imsave` (or alternatives from other libraries, *e.g.* opencv's `imwrite`, or the tools from `PIL`, etc). The reason for this is that `plt.savefig` is implemented to save the entire figure, which means saving axes, labels, text etc. Furthermore, it takes a boolean argument `Transparent` which will handle the fourth channel. So, without knowing the inner workings and exact implementation of `plt.savefig`, it's a safe bet to say that it shouldn't be used to save grayscale images.

In your case however, since you're not using `plt.savefig` to plot anything besides the image itself, there is a simple workaround that I'll come to after covering two points in your question. First, your code is

```
plt.imshow(data[:, 400:650].T)
```

but since you want a grayscale image, you should set `cmap="gray"`. Second, regarding this part

> When storing just a single-channel image in png format, the image is all black

There isn't any info in your question on the range of values that are in your `data`, but I'm guessing that this is just an issue of "float" vs "uint8" datatype. Try setting `data.astype(float64)` or if using `uint8`, make sure you normalize it in `[0,255]` and not `[0,1]`.

Now regarding the simple workaround, once you've figured out how to correct the above and saved your figure, you'll notice when loading the image with `plt.imread` that all your four channels have the same values (assuming you've set `cmap=gray`), so you can just select any of the four channels and discard the others.

But again, it's a better idea to use `plt.imsave` or opencv.